# In cxfreeze, can I specify the python version I want the executable to use?

Tags: opencv, cx-freeze

Situation:
In my Mac Os 10.8.5 I have available python2.7 and python2.7-32 with latest cx_freeze(-4.3.2).

I need cx_freeze to pick the python2.7-32 version so my executable app can use a 32-bit version of OpenCV.

So far, all attempts to use cx_freeze script suggest that it bundles python2.7(which is 64bit) and the app fails to execute with: "cv2.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture"
(This is the same error you would get if you try to import OpenCV built in 32 bits, with a python interpreter of 64)

Is there a way to "force" cxfreeze to bundle a specific python version installed (in this case python2.7-32) in the executable it produces?

Edit:
I've also tried to build cx-freeze from source in 32-bit using:

> python2.7-32 setup.py build;
>   python2.7-32 setup.py install

No matter what, the app generated is still a 64bit version:

> $ python2.7-32 setup.py bdist_dmg
>
> $ file capturebasic
>   capturebasic: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
>
> $ arch -i386 ./capturebasic
>   arch: posix_spawnp: ./capturebasic: Bad CPU type in executable

Edit2:
It seems that Mac's cx_freeze you download from sourceforge is only 64-bit:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.3.2/

If you want to create 32-bit apps, you need the 32-bit version of cx_freeze.

I'm confirming if there's any way to install the 32bit version in Mac in cx_freeze's mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not have to touch your setup script, but just change the command used to build it. For instance instead of using `python setup.py build`, you would use the command `python2.7-32 setup.py build`. You may have to specify the path to the python2.7-32 exe. so something like `path\to\python2.7-32.exe setup.py build`. Note: I use windows so the example commands I used might be a little different on mac, like instead of `.exe` it's `.app`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was obsessed with the script and I did not try the setup.py option, unfortunately it didn't do the trick either.